# keep operation running on ec2-server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

On my windows machine, I connect with Putty over SSH to an ec2 Linux instance and perform a download through the command line from a public web resource. When my internet connection has a hick-up the connection of my Putty terminal to the server gets lost.

My question relates to why the download operation does not continue to run on the ec2-server independent of me having a terminal window open. How can I make sure that the operation continues to run on the instance when I close my connection to it ?

There are already couple similar questions, but the answers seem not applicable to my situation.

Comment: Short answer - use `screen`. Longer answer - questions like this are a better fit for serverfault or superuser rather than Stack Overflow. It's not specific to ec2, it applies to any server where your ssh connection might get cut off.

Comment: thanks - got it. I have no experience with anything else than stackoverflow but will check it out.

Comment: `nohup` can be used if you just want a single command to complete. `screen` is to be used to keep a terminal session alive regardless of connection.